# Where is the uniform distribution with one parameter ($U(\theta, k \theta)$) useful for modelling?

Tags: distributions, modeling, uniform-distribution, application

I recently came across the distribution $U(\theta, k \theta)$ (where k is known) in the context of statistical theory (as a nice toy example for finding MLE and the likes).

However, I was wondering if there are real use cases where one might wish to use this distribution for modelling something. But I couldn't seem to find any paper using this (or similar) distribution for actual data.

My question is if you happen to know of such a use for this distribution (or one similar to it). And more generally, how can one search for it effectively?

Comment: See the [German Tank Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem)

Comment: It might be of interest to note that the logarithm of a variable with this distribution would be a doubly truncated Exponential variable.